# что(,) по-мОему(,) должно быть сделано

Tags: запятые

Нужны ли запятые? Дело в том, что в данном случае нельзя убрать вводные слова – на них делается мегасуперударение и они – суть.

`Я делаю только тО, что(,) по-мОему(,) должно быть сделано.`

`Я делаю только тО, что должно быть сделано(,) по мОему мнению.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ будет здесь. Пожалуйста, дочитайте до конца, потому что, только дочитав до конца, вы поймете, как надо, и поймете все возможные варианты.

---

Вводное слово **обособляется в любом случае**, падает на них логическое ударение или нет.

И вводное слово в любом случае можно убрать из предложения без потери структуры. Даже если нарушится смысл, запятые нужны, если это вводные слова, потому что в любом справочнике говорится именно о структуре, — смысл не упоминается никогда.

Поэтому правильно:

***Я делаю только т, что, по-моему, должно быть сделано***;

***Я делаю только то, что должно быть сделано, по моему мнению***.

Это **обязательная пунктуация**, если вы это подразумеваете как вводные слова.

---

Впрочем, возможен и вариант без запятых:

***Я делаю только то, что по-моему должно быть сделано***;

***Я делаю только то, что должно быть сделано по моему мнению***.

Здесь вводных слов нет, ***по-моему*** и ***по моему мнению*** — обстоятельства, к которым задается наречный вопрос:

*Должно быть сделано (как?) **по-моему***;

*Должно быть сделано (как?) **по моему мнению***.

---

Поэтому пунктуация зависит от того, что имел в виду автор.